# System navigation bar animation

Tags: android, android-animation

I am trying to reproduce system navigation hide/show animation.

I found some window animation attrs in sdk sources, but can't figure out timing/interpolators.

```
com.android.internal.R.styleable.WindowAnimation_windowEnterAnimation
com.android.internal.R.styleable.WindowAnimation_windowExitAnimation
com.android.internal.R.styleable.WindowAnimation_windowShowAnimation
com.android.internal.R.styleable.WindowAnimation_windowHideAnimation
```

Can anybody help me?

p.s.
for hide I use `View.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION`

[image]

Comment: How do you mean, exactly? Those are just attributes that you would assign an `anim` resource to; just like you'd assign a `color` or `drawable` resource to `windowBackground`.

Comment: @MikeM. I want to animate my view to move with system navigation. Because of this I want to reproduce system navigation animation.

Comment: @MikeM. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: I'm really not sure what you mean by "system navigation animation".

Comment: @MikeM. I added description to question.

Comment: Oh, the navigation bar. Hmm, I'm not sure. Let me see what I can find out about that.

Comment: Yeesh, I don't know if I'm looking in the wrong spot, or there's something obvious that I'm missing, but I just cannot find where that sliding animation/transition is defined and applied. All I can find is the fading alpha animation. Anyway, if you wanna have a dig around, the core classes for that bar are here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/packages/SystemUI/src/com/android/systemui/statusbar/phone.

Comment: thanks, I'll look this way